# How to make fields readonly while updating

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I have a form. Once the form is filled I don't want the user to change anything in the form.

But the user can see the values. Meaning all the fields are non editable. I can do this by using instance method but this does not help in foreignkey.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use readonlyAdmin

Comment: Oh yah.. that's very "simple" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean "once the form is filled".

If it's an html form post, just render a new html page with simple text and values of the submitted form.

If the post-back was an ajax call, you can change the CSS-styling of the  elements for example and disable the submit button or erase the whole  and substitute the values that you get back from ajax request.

There is no "editable=False" property on html input elements btw.

Comment: i know but if it can be simple then why not use that